# From date should not be greater than To date using react hooks and typescript

Tags: datetime, validation, react-hooks, react-typescript

I am working with validations in which if the date entered in "from" input date is greater than "ToDate" it should through error. I am new to using react with typescript. This is what I did: There are two component files:
**AdvancedSearch.tsx**

```
const initialErrors = {
    dateValidity: false,
    dateErrorMsg: "test message"
  };
  const initialDates = {
    assignedFrom: null,
    assignedTo: null
  };
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState(initialErrors);
  const [dates, setDates] = useState(initialDates);
  useEffect(() => {
    validateDates();
    
  }, [dates]);
  console.log(dates);

  function validateDates() {
    
    let dateErrorMsg: string = "";
    let dateValidity: boolean = false;

    const dateRangeCheck = new Date(dates.assignedFrom) <= new Date(dates.assignedTo);

    dateErrorMsg = dateRangeCheck ? "" : "End date can't be before start date.";
    dateValidity = dateRangeCheck ? false : true; // true if error - end date before start date

    setErrors((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      dateValidity,
      dateErrorMsg,
    }));
  }
```

and in my input field for date i am handling it like this:

```
<div className="row job-search-content">
                    <div className="col-md-2">
                        <label className="spg-label">Assigned/Queued From</label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-9">
                        <input
                            className="spg-input spg-input-component spg-input--medium"
                            type={jobSearchForm?.showTime ? 'datetime-local' : 'date'}
                            onChange={(event) => {
                                handleChange(event, 'assignedFrom', 'date');
                            }}
                            value={jobSearchForm?.assignedFrom}
                        ></input>
                            <span className="validation-error">{errors.dateErrorMsg}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
     <div className="row job-search-content">
                    <div className="col-md-2">
                        <label className="spg-label">Assigned/Queued To</label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-9">
                        <input
                            className="spg-input spg-input-component spg-input--medium"
                            type={jobSearchForm?.showTime ? 'datetime-local' : 'date'}
                            onChange={(event) => {
                                handleChange(event, 'assignedTo', 'date');
                            }}
                            value={jobSearchForm?.assignedTo}
                        ></input>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

now the problem is its not showing the validation error because it's not triggering the handle change event and the definition of that handle change event is in another file **Finder.tsx** where I am handling other logic as well. So now please help me understand how should I trigger this handle change event as the date values are staying in the previous state with null values when i check it in console log.

```
 const handleChange = (e, fieldName: string, role: string) => {
    if (fieldName) {
      setJobSearchForm((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        [fieldName]: role == 'date' ? e.target.value : e,
      }));
      if (fieldName == 'showTime') {
        setJobSearchForm((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          assignedFrom: '',
          assignedTo: '',
          completedFrom: '',
          completedTo: '',
        }));
      }-------------------------
```

[image]